# WCF client cannot find configuration file

Tags: .net, wcf, app-config

Consider the following situation:

A WCF host named preorderservice

A console exe named server.exe with engine.dll

engine.dll has a valid proxy to preorderservice

system.servicemodel is added to server.exe.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="netTcppreorderservice" openTimeout="00:01:00" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/ServicesHost/preorderservice/preorderservice"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcppreorderservice"
            contract="preorderservice.Ipreorderservice" name="netTcppreorderservice">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

then the client is created with this endpoint config name

```
proxy = new preorderserviceclient("netTcppreorderservice");
```

But the exception

System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find endpoint element with name 'netTcppreorderservice' and contract 'preorderservice.Ipreorderservice' in the ServiceModel client configuration section
This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

But the names are correct and other config settings are found in that file, I have no clue how to fix this.

And typing out the WCF proxy creation when reading the Uri from the config works so the config is found.....

```
            EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["preorderservice"]); 

            Ipreorderservice proxy = ChannelFactory<Ipreorderservice>.CreateChannel(new NetTcpBinding(), ep);
```

By request, edited in the whole config, some AppSettings are snipped out. It uses AppFabric too which does work and it is a WCF service too.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataCacheClient" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,&#xD;&#xA;            Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, &#xD;&#xA;            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </configSections>
  <dataCacheClient maxConnectionsToServer="6">
    <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
    <hosts>
      <host name="w2k8cache" cachePort="22233" />
    </hosts>
  </dataCacheClient>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Local.Labs" value="50,51" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="Engine" value="4" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" port="1966" clientConnectionLimit="32">
          <serverProviders>
            <formatter ref="binary" />
          </serverProviders>
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="netTcppreorderservice" openTimeout="00:01:00" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/ServicesHost/preorderservice/preorderservice"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpRopsPreorderService"
            contract="preOrderservice.Ipreorderservice" name="netTcppreorderservice">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you entered this by hand or used the WCF Configuration Tool?

Comment: In your Server.exe project, do you have references to System.Configuration.dll and System.ServiceModel.dll?

Comment: it was generated and both the references exist

Comment: May I confirm that server.exe is a .NET console app with static reference to engine.dll? also would you mind post the whole server.exe.config?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration has to be located in engine.dll.config if my memory is good.
And I pretty sure that you can define your own configuration file if you want to use server.exe.config.